# Why am I getting segmentation fault while implementing linked list?

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, initialization, singly-linked-list

In this function, I get segmentation fault. I think it has something to do with memory allocation.  What mistake am I making?

Now, if I initialize Node* a =NULL, i get my head pointer as NULL in the end.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    Node(int x) {
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

Node* addTwoLists(Node* first, Node* second) {
    // Code here
    Node *a;
    Node *head = a;
    int bor = 0;
    while(first->next && second->next) {
        int ans = first->data + second->data;
        a = new Node((ans%10)+bor);
        bor = ans/10;
        a=a->next;
        first = first->next;
        second = second->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your program in a debugger, examining the values of relevant variables and how they change at each step? If not, you should do that. Debugging is an essential programmer skill.

Comment: Side note: not sure `Node *head = a;` behaves the way you think it does. Not 100% sure on that, though.

Comment: Changing `a` later on will not magically change `head` which contains garbage. You need to assign the first Node to head

Comment: If your lists are not the same length, not checking for `nullptr` before doing `first = first->next;
        second = second->next;` could result in a crash.

Comment: @Chipster The check is the loop condition.

Comment: @eerorika sigh. Missed that that would check it for null. Thanks.

Comment: Also, as I think Stroustrup put it, teachers need to stop teaching C and teach C++

Comment: "*What mistake am I making?*" - implementing a linked list by hand, instead of using the standard `std::list` or `std::forward_list` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the allocation, it's the pointer use that is all wrong.

Here's how it should look. This code maintains a variable `last` which is the last node added to the list. You need this variable so you can at the end of the list. You were obviously trying to do this yourself, but got the logic wrong.

```
Node* addTwoLists(Node* first, Node* second) {
    Node *last = NULL;
    Node *head = NULL;
    int bor = 0;
    while(first->next && second->next) {
        int ans = first->data + second->data;
        Node* a = new Node((ans%10)+bor);
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = last = a; // first node, update head and end of list
        }
        else {
            last->next = a; // add a to the end of the list
            last = a;       // update the end of the list
        }
        bor = ans/10;
        first = first->next;
        second = second->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Untested code.

Answer (score 6):

1. `a` is uninitialized. You must not use `a` until you assign a value
2. you never again assign to `head`, so it could never be anything else.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the variable `head` has indeterminate value and is not changed in the function.

```
Node *a;
Node *head = a;
```

Changing the variable `a` does not mean changing of the value of the expression `a->next`.

```
// ...
a = new Node((ans%10)+bor);
//...
a=a->next;
```

The function can be written the following way (without testing)

```
Node * addTwoLists( const Node *first, const Node *second ) 
{
    const int Base = 10;

    Node *head = nullptr;

    int bor = 0;

    Node **current = &head;

    for ( ; first != nullptr && second != nullptr; first = first->next, second = second->next )
    { 
        int sum = first->data + second->data + bor;
        *current = new Node( sum % Base );
        bor = sum / Base;
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    if ( bor )
    {
        *current = new Node( bor );
    }

    return head;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node 
{
    explicit Node( int data, Node *next = nullptr ) : data( data ), next( next )
    {
    }

    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void push_front( Node **head, int x )
{
    *head = new Node( x, *head );
}

Node * addTwoLists( const Node *first, const Node *second ) 
{
    const int Base = 10;

    Node *head = nullptr;

    int bor = 0;

    Node **current = &head;

    for ( ; first != nullptr && second != nullptr; first = first->next, second = second->next )
    { 
        int sum = first->data + second->data + bor;
        *current = new Node( sum % Base );
        bor = sum / Base;
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    if ( bor )
    {
        *current = new Node( bor );
    }

    return head;
}

std::ostream & display_list( const Node *head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( ; head != nullptr; head = head->next )
    {
        os << head->data << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    Node *list1 = nullptr;
    Node *list2 = nullptr;

    for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ ) push_front( &list1, i );
    for ( int i = N; --i != 0; ) push_front( &list2, i );

    display_list( list1 ) << '\n';
    display_list( list2 ) << '\n';

    Node *list3 = addTwoLists( list1, list2 );

    display_list( list3 ) << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Two star code! Correct but maybe a bit tricky for someone who doesn't understand ordinary pointers?

Comment: @john I prefer three star cognac.:)

Answer (score 0):

You may get segmentation fault for various reasons here.

1. If `first` or `second` is *NULL* then you will get segmentation fault. So make sure that if these two nodes are not *NULL*.
2. You didn't **initialize** a. So initialize it first.

And as you want `head` variable should contain starting node of the answer list so you need to assign node whenever you get start of the list.

Just add this line after `a = new Node((ans%10)+bor);`

```
if(head == NULL) head = a;
```

Comment: 1. I actually thought that too, but it's wrong. See my conversation on the original question.

Comment: I started writing this before your comment. That's why I didn't notice it.

Comment: That makes sense.